# AS3 regular expressions make html tags uppercase

Tags: html, regex, actionscript-3

I would like to transform a string containing HTML tags such that all tags and properties will be in upper case (using regular expressions preferably).

For example, the following string:

```
'<bla>something <br/><a href="foo">bar</a></bla>'
```

should be changed to

```
'<BLA>something <BR/><A HREF="foo">bar</A></BLA>'
```

Is this possible using a single string replace with a regular expression? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Changing just the HTML element tag names to uppercase is pretty easy. Use the callback function version of the String replace method like so:

```js
function HtmlTagName2Upper(text) {
    return text.replace(/(<\/?\w+\b)([^<>]*>)/g,
                function(m0, m1, m2) {
                    return m1.toUpperCase() + m2;});
}
```

The above regex captures the tag name in `$1` and all the attributes (if any) in `$2`. The above regex will work pretty well but does not handle attribute values having angle brackets and does not uppercase the attribute names.

Handling HTML elements having angle brackets in their attribute values and making the element attribute names uppercase is a bit more involved:

```js
function HtmlTagAndAttributeNames2Upper(text) {
    return text.replace(/(<\/?\w+\b)((?:[^<>'"]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>)/g,
                function(mo0, mo1, mo2) {
                    mo2 = mo2.replace(/(\s+[\w\-.:]+)((?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[\w\-.:]+))?)/g,
                            function(mi0, mi1, mi2) {
                                return mi1.toUpperCase() + mi2});
                    return mo1.toUpperCase() + mo2;});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not an expert of AS3. However a **work-around** could be the following:

1. Find all the html tags through a regexp like this: `<[^>]+>`
2. Substitute all the *html tags* found with their upper case version (by using the `toUpperCase()` method).

Comment: i thoght of something like that, but how to apply 'toUpperCase' only to maches of a regular expression? and also, this would change the values of tag properties to uppercase too. for example it would change <a href ="foo"> to <A HREF = "FOO"> istead of <A HREF="foo">

Comment: For each tag returned by your regexp:

1: strip angular braces `<>`. Get the tag text content enclosed.
2: Use the `split(/\s+/)` method: Get the tag name and uppercase it.
3: for each `attribute=value` split it `split(/=/)` and get the attribute names. Uppercase them.
4. Concatenate the resulting string. `'<'` + `upperCaseTagName` + `attributeUppercase`=`attributeValue`* + `>`
5. Replace the old string with the new one.